How to remove too many nested steps in Allure Reports?
I'm working on this project using webdriverio, cucumber and allure reports.
The reports have a weird 4-5 levels deep nesting issue when a test step is broken or times-out or fails. On the last step executed (deepest leaf) I can find the attached screenshot where the test has failed.
the tests are written in JS with cucumber feature files and the necessary steps glue code .
The allure report is new addon to the wdio config
